# Use virtualenv in production without python-dev

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, production-environment

I have a python web project and I use virtualenv with pip on my dev server. 
Some python packages require compilation, so I should have python-dev in order to pip install them.
Is there a way to reproduce my requirements stack in production keeping virtualenv, but no python-dev, as I am dealing with no dev server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pip 1.4 added support for installing and building wheel package.

> "Wheel" is a built, archive format that can greatly speed installation compared to building and installing from source archives.

### procedure

1. Install/upgrade to pip 1.4. (one time only)
2. Install `wheel` in both dev, production server. (one time only)

   ```
   pip install wheel
   ```
3. Build wheel package in dev server:

   ```
   pip wheel --wheel-dir=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
   ```
4. Transfer `/local/wheels` packages to production server.
5. Install packages in production server:

   ```
   pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
   ```

### Reference

See [pip documentation about building and installing wheels](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.4/cookbook.html#building-and-installing-wheels) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks, great upgrade with wheel !

Comment: Have to upgrade also setuptools to 0.9.8 inside the virtualenv in order to make wheels.

Comment: I'm not able to create wheels for both MySQL-python & uWSGI without python-dev! Seems like python-dev want to follow our production servers to death. Do you have any experiences with ? May be I should try to build those wheels with python-dev on the dev server and install them in production without python-dev installed ?

Comment: @ScotchAndSoda, You need compiler, python-dev in dev server while create wheel.

Comment: This is curious, the wheels that I create on the dev server with python-dev do not install on the production side as wheels should be installable on both x86 & 64 arch.

Comment: @ScotchAndSoda, I think so. BTW, dev/production should share same platform (at least platform should match).